# Asp.net MVC Bulk Printing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, kendo-ui

I am using OpenXml to read and replace bookmarks from the word document in my Asp.net MVC application using Kendo UI. I have like thousands of records coming from the database and to each record i have to open the document replace the bookmarks and then print it i have done the bookmarks replace with text part using OpenXml but i am not able to print the document i was using sever side printing which is working in my vs2010 but not in IIS so what should i do or what is the best solution to accomplish my task

Comment: you want someone on their web browser to be able to print something in your datacenter?

Comment: this application is for the school system so it would be installed in their servers and it can be access locally

Comment: We are probably going to need to see the code that you are trying to print. Its probably a permissions issue since you control the environment you could change the app pool user to one that has proper permissions

Comment: i need a code to print from the client side

Comment: to print from the client side, call window.print()

Comment: i am not sure how use window.print from the client side because i am using mvc4 and inside the controller there is one loop which opens the document using OpenXML and replaces the bookmarks and then i need a print function so there can be thousands of documents so how to print each document from the controller

Comment: I'm with you until you said there are "thousands of documents". Where did thousands come from? How long is that going to take even if you got it working? You really want to do that?

Comment: My scenerio is there is a single word template which has some bookmarks what i want to do is ..there are thousands for students so for each student i want to open a word document replace bookmarks and then print the document and i have to do it for all students. I am using openxml to write data in the word file but to print each document what should i do? i  need your suggestion i was using System.Diagnostics.Process P = new Process(); which works fine in my VS210 and in IIS i am getting an error "Default printer is not set."

Comment: Honestly I dont think this sounds like a web app. This should be written as a WPF app or console app or something like that.

Comment: actually this is a part of web project which i am developing for a school and all functions have been done i am just stuck in the printing job and i am not sure what to do

Comment: Just try changing the app pool user to LocalSystem or something and see if it is a permissions problem. Go from there.

Comment: already tried this i even set the printer name to P.StartInfo.Arguments = "Microsoft XPS Document Writer"; but no success and i can see 3 printers when i debug in IIS but it says Default printer is not set.

Comment: Sure, because the localsystem account doesnt have a default printer. Try setting app pool user to your user account.

Comment: how to set my user account?

Comment: i tried this i am able to get the default printer but it completes the print document code without throwing any error but still it doesnot print the document

Comment: One thing you haven't clarified is what the workflow is. I'm assuming: 1. User A logs into your app, 2. User enters some data and clicks "Print", 3. You open the Word document, then for each selected student, 4. do replacements and print the document with replaced data for one student. This gives one big document per "Print", and it contains data for all students. How well did I guess?

Comment: yes john i am thinking the same to combine all in one document and then print it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same scenario to implement and the same question.
I need ability to print several letters for different students from client machine (up to 90 000 letters)
What I implemented by the moment is: I am generating many html pages on the server side, converting them to one pdf document with autoprint action set on open event and sending it to client on separate tab. So when client downloads this pdf it prompts for printing.But this works for small amount of letters (<1000) only.

What I am thinking of now is to implement client-side printer application (exe or applet) which will get the task from server and print letters one by one to printer directly.